# Top 1 with ties with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the latest value from column ks_data_operacji for each sp_numer. It works but the problem is that the result should be made dependent on column ksd_ksksub_id. If ksd_ksksub_id=2 then I'd like to get the second latest value.
Here's my code:

```
select top 1 with ties
sp_numer,
CAST(ks_data_operacji as date) as data_ostatniej_wplaty

from sprawa
join ksiegowanie_dekret on ksd_rb_id=sp_rb_id
join ksiegowanie on ksd_ks_id=ks_id
where sp_numer=102079 and ksd_ksksub_id<>2
order by ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sp_numer order by   
ks_data_operacji desc)
```

Sample data:

```
create table ##temp ( sp_numer varchar(10), ks_data_operacji date,    
ksd_ksksub_id int ) 

insert into ##temp 
values (102079,'2013-07-24',5), 
(102079,'2013-10-03',6)
,(102079,'2015-11-17',2)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I need to get value 2013-10-03 and when I created temporary table it works. I don't know why it doesn't work in my production database.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @Arkadiusz What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: The latest date is 2015-11-17 but ksd_ksksub_id=2 so my desired outcome is 2013-10-03.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Ok I see I write an answer hope can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add the condition to the `order by`:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by sp_numer
                            order by (case when ksd_ksksub_id = 2 then 1 else 2 end),
                                     ks_data_operacji desc
                           )
```

That is, make the "second" row "first".

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `CTE` make row number by `ROW_NUMBER` window function then `self-join` by `ksd_ksksub_id` and `rn = 1`

```
create table temp ( sp_numer varchar(10), ks_data_operacji date,    
ksd_ksksub_id int ) ;

insert into temp 
values (102079,'2013-07-24',5), 
(102079,'2013-10-03',6)
,(102079,'2015-11-17',2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sp_numer order by ks_data_operacji desc) rn
    FROM temp 
)
SELECT t2.*
FROM CTE t1 
JOIN CTE t2 on t1.rn = 1 and t1.ksd_ksksub_id = t2.rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f39f1/1/0)**:

```
| sp_numer | ks_data_operacji | ksd_ksksub_id | rn |
|----------|------------------|---------------|----|
|   102079 |       2013-10-03 |             6 |  2 |
```